# Page manager selection rules for a variant for the front page

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I'm trying to make a Ctools page variant for the front page but I'm not sure of the of the selection rules I need to use to make it apply to the front page.   I've tried making it apply to everything BUT any of the existing content types but that didn't work.

Does anyone know of a set of selection rules that can let me target the front page?

Thanks

Comment: You can type any new name for your custom page, but when check flag «Make this your site home page».

Answer (score 1):

If fron page point to "node" (in Site information administering page), just change it to show some selected node (blank node for example), then edit this node in panels as you want, if you want list nodes, enable there views...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.   Do you know of a way of doing it without assigning the front to a specific node and then using views?

Comment: I cann't say now, need to test ctools on "node" page. But what's problem with assigning? You can simulate node listing via Views module.